# When inputting a file, can I extract the title as a section header?

Tags: input

To move sections and sections down the hierarchy, I have:

```
\let\section\subsection
\let\subsection\subsubsection
```

In case it's needed, here is ExampleFile.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Example file}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Monday}
\subsection{Topic}


\end{document}
```

And the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Week 1}
{
\let\section\subsection
\let\subsection\subsubsection
\input{ExampleFile.tex}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you move `\title` after `\begin{document}` in the subfile? If yes, you could redefined title as section

Comment: You can redefine `\maketitle` to `section`, but you'll need some logic to somehow move it after the `\tableofcontents`, and you'll need to know where the `\title` is stored (I think it's in `\@title` or something...? You'll have to dig the source code for this)

Comment: Using `\input` you will have two `\documentclass` commands.  See the subfile package.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It never occurred to me to try that! I think that counts as an answer. The more general solutions are definitely relevant but probably fall under "harder than doing it manually"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick hack, you could move the `\title` to the document body of your subfile and redefine it as section.

Please note that if your real subfile happens to use hyperref and you want meaningful meta data in the pdf, then you will have to manually set it as having the title in the document body is too late for hyperref to pick it up automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{ExampleFile.tex}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{Example file}
\author{}
\maketitle

\section{Monday}
\subsection{Topic}


\end{document}  
\end{filecontents*}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

{\let\title\section
\let\section\subsection
\let\subsection\subsubsection
\input{ExampleFile.tex}}

\end{document}
```

[image]